# How to overlay a masked plot in Seaborn where ax have different columns? - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The goal is to get these two plots to overlay each other.  The goal is to get the appearance of a subdivision in some of the rows.  By printing a graph with more columns, and then overlaying it with a graph of fewer columns, we can get that effect.

However calling the second ax is completely overwriting the first.

How can we achieve this effect?

EDIT*

I believe that ax labels might be a clue.

```
ax.set_label("axes1")
ax2 = fig.add_axes(ax.get_position(), frameon=False, label='axes2') #$ax.twinx()
```

creating a second ax2 like this and then calling:

```
ax2.get_label()
ax.get_label()
```

shows the correct and different labels.  However after running the following code:

```
x1 = np.array([[30., 30.],
              [20., 20.],
              [10., 10.]])
x2 = np.concatenate((x1, x1), axis=1)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
indexes = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]
columns = ["First", "Second"]
columns2 = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"]

y1 = pd.DataFrame(data=x1, index=indexes, columns=columns)
y2 = pd.DataFrame(data=x2, index=indexes, columns=columns2)

ax = sns.heatmap(y2, mask=x2 <= .0, annot=False, cbar=False, linewidths=.5)
ax2 = sns.heatmap(y1, mask=x1 >= .0, annot=False, cbar=False, linewidths=.5)
```

The labels have become the same.  This would mean that it isn't printing two axes, it's simply writing one 2 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to call heatmap in this case was to use the ax as an argument for sns.heatmap()

```
sns.heatmap(y2, mask=x2 <= .0, annot=False, cbar=False, linewidths=.5, ax=ax)
sns.heatmap(y1, mask=x1 >= 21.0, annot=False, cbar=False, linewidths=.5, ax=ax2)
```